# Logging stack suggestion website

Tags: web-apps, logs

couple of months ago I came across a website that allowed the user to pick individual components of a logging solution and it showed which ones were compatible with each other. Also giving links to documentation of such components.

Problem is, I can't remember the name of that site, and I really needed it once again. Just spent 4 hours on google and couldn't find it...

Hope someone knows which site I'm talking about.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it! I'll leave it here so that others can benefit from it
https://openapm.io